# TYPO3 form - password forgot link change E-Mail content

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a login form on my page. I found an option in the backend so that users can reset their password.

I tried it and it works, I received an E-Mail with a link to a page where I can change the password.

However, I try to change the content of the E-Mail because I don't like it.

**I found this:**

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['forgotPasswordMail']
```

Hook to change the contents of the forgot password mail

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/Hooks/Index.html

I found this "[Tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Hooks/Concept/Index.html#using-hooks)" which shows how to use hooks, but it is missing some important information. Where exactly do I have to do the manipulation? In which file? How exactly do I replace the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "simple" change the lang parameters for `felogin` to change the email content.

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1._LOCAL_LANG {
  default {
    ll_forgot_email_password (
... Your Text here for emails with password ...
    )
    ll_forgot_email_nopassword (
... Your Text here for emails where password can not found ...
    )
    ll_forgot_validate_reset_password(
... Here Text for emails with password reset link ...
    )
  }
}
```

You can see the default Text with placeholders [here](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/felogin/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf#L99).

There first line of the translation is used as the subject of the email.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and report back.

Comment: I forgot to notice that the first line of the translation variable is used to be the subject of the email.

Comment: Ok so I copied your config 1:1 to the template setup of the login page, but the email content did not changed. I also cleared the cache before. Maybe this is not working with my TYPO3 version? I noticed that "_LOCAL_LANG" was not even in the autocompletion.
I think I have to change the xlf file directly

Comment: Do you have an other frontend language like german or so? Maybe you should use `de` instead of `default`.

Comment: Yes that was the right hint! My default language is indeed german and after changing `default` to `de` it works! :)